# Exclude some tables

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

`SHOW TABLES IN database '*match*'`

I want to exclude tables that end on `old`. Any tips on how this regex syntax work?

Answer (score 1):

[`SHOW TABLES`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/show-tables.html) allows only [`LIKE`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/comparison.html#like) patterns (but not `NOT LIKE`), so you can use it:

```sql
SHOW TABLES
FROM schema -- optional, if not present current schema will be used
LIKE '%match%'
```

Which will return all tables with names containing `match`.

If you want to filter out tables - better would be to query `information_schema.tables`:

```sql
select *
from information_schema.tables
where table_name not like '%old' -- filter out tables ending with "old"
```